How to debug/edit dependency that only has type declaration files
I need to access and debug/change the code of one of our dependencies containing custom Angular components from a different repository. This repository gets included via a self-hosted npm registry in the package.json.
I have tried to replace the remote dependency with a link to the local repository, but then the application throws an error (compiling is fine, but when you access the localhost website I get an error that XYZ is not a function, some mapping must be broken).
When I go to the node_modules/ folder and look for the dependency, all I see are type declaration files (foobar.d.ts) and not the actual code or I'd just try and change that while debugging.
When I install the dependency via the local repository, I get the actual code in the node_modules/, but some mapping/includes somewhere must have an issue with the namespace declaration or something, I'm not sure.
How can I debug this without having to publish every change to the registry and update the modules?

Not all dependencies are designed to be run directly from the source code - most, especially where TS is involved, have some kind of build process to create the published artifacts. If you've really only got type declarations, maybe you've actually installed a @types/ package (or code is somehow generated from those).

You're right, there's various @types devDependencies in the project. Is there a way to work around this or perhaps generate the needed module from my local repository so that I can just overwrite the needed files/directory?

I've found that using ng build (and some configuration) I can make a generate a new build landing in ./dist where I can find all the files, folders and type declaration files that I can also find in the node_modules directory of our main project. I have replaced the whole node_modules.some-dependency folder with the newly generated one, but my changes are still not visible (even though I can see that they're there in the file itself).

The solution was rather simple in hindsight.
Simply generate the needed type declaration files with ng build. Depending on your configs, the destination for the generated folder may vary.
For me, the dependency landed in /dependencyRepoName/dist. Now I only needed to go link it and install it in my project.
For that, I simply execute npm link in the source code of my dependency. In my case, that was /dependencyRepoName/project.
Next, I switch to my project, where I navigate to the client folder containing my frontend and execute npm link dependencyRepoName followed by npm i ../pathToRepo/dependencyRepoName/dist
This should install the local version of your dependency and link it so that every time you update the dependency code (you may need to rebuild your dependency with ng build), your project app rebuilds and shows the changes.
